# How to paint bottom area of custom keyboard(Keyboard Kit)

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am using custom keyboard(Keyboard Kit). I have default view and advanced view. [Default view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRdH4.png) is a default keyboard, [advanced view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIw0p.png) opens view with different ui elements. You can see difference in colors on second image. I want to set color of bottom area the same as advanced view background color.

I tried to make constraints of advanced view equal to superview but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.